# Changing a string's text when a button is pressed in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to figure out how to change the text of a string when a button is pressed in SwiftUI.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           let title = Text("Button Not Clicked")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .padding()
                .frame(height: 0.0)
        }
        
        Button(action: {
            title.text = "Button Clicked!"
        }) {
            Text("Click Here")
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

So far, I've tried to change the string using 'title.text = (string)' but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of declaring the string in the body property you can declare it as a `@State var buttonTitle: String = "Button Not Clicked"` on ContentView. Then you just need to put `buttonTitle = "Button Clicked"` in your action closure.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var buttonTitle: String = "Button Not Clicked"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           Text(buttonTitle)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .padding()
                .frame(height: 0.0)

            Button(action: {
                buttonTitle = "Button Clicked!"
            }) {
                Text("Click Here")
            }
        }
        

    }
    
    
}
```

The UIKit way would be to try to access the label and change its string, but in SwiftUI your body property will effectively be recalculated every time the View updates.

Additional example showing multiple strings being stored in a dictionary:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var labels: [String : String] = [
        "header" : "This Is the header!",
        "donger" : "",
        "footer" : "Here's the footer."
        
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(labels["header"]!)
            Text(labels["donger"]!)
            Text(labels["footer"]!)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Update") {
                updateDonger()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateDonger() {
        labels["donger"] = #"╰( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡° )つ──☆*:・ﾟ"#
    }
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to have multiple editable text elements in a VStack, would I declare every one as a @State variable?

Comment: @Piie. If you have a new question please create another post. If your original question was answered please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: You probably would want to use a separate `@State` variable for each string, but you could use a dictionary of strings instead. I can update the example to show a different example with a dictionary. There are a few other approaches you could take, such as using ObservableObject to create a view model. That's a bit out of scope for this question though.

Comment: @Sparklebeard please show with a Dict :DD: